# How to split array of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
[{50: 2, 75: 3, 99: 4}, {50: 5, 75: 6, 99: 7}, {50: 8, 75: 9, 99:10}]
```

The following is an array of dictionaries in Python. I want to convert the array into following three arrays in Python:

```
[2, 5, 8] # corresponding to 50.
[3, 6, 9] # corresponding to 75.
[4, 7, 9] # corresponding to 99.
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that all dicts in the list have the same keys?Is the number of keys always 3?

Comment: yes, all dict's will have same key

Comment: FYI, Python calls these lists, and they behave a lot more like ArrayLists than arrays. Comments are `#` and there are no semicolons. You may wish to clarify your question and tag accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

One way may be to use `defaultdict` such that it is dictionary with values of `list` corresponding to keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [{50: 2, 75: 3, 99: 4}, {50: 5, 75: 6, 99: 7}, {50: 8, 75: 9, 99:10}] 
my_dict_list = defaultdict(list)

for value in my_list:
    for k,v in value.items():
        my_dict_list[k].append(v)
```

And the list of values for each can be accessed by keys as below:

```
print(my_dict_list[50])
```

Answer (score 3):

A Python dict is an unsorted collection, at least it is before Python 3.6, so you can't guarantee that the keys retain insertion order. And since you want the keys to be in numerical order we need to sort them.

Then we can use a list comprehension to extract the corresponding values from each dict in the list, and use tuple assignment to assign each of the list to a separate name.

```
data = [{50: 2, 75: 3, 99: 4}, {50: 5, 75: 6, 99: 7}, {50: 8, 75: 9, 99:10}]
a, b, c = [[d[k] for d in data] for k in sorted(data[0].keys())]
```

FWIW, it may be more convenient to save the output as a single list of lists, rather than as 3 separate lists.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your list is stored as `l`, you can use `zip` to transpose the dict values within:

```
list(zip(*(d.values() for d in l)))
```

This returns:

```
[(2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9), (4, 7, 10)]
```

Comment: If you change the order of the keys in any one dictionary, this will not produce the correct answer. As pointed out by @PM2Ring, the order is not guaranteed prior to 3.6.

Comment: I guess something like `list(zip(*(OrderedDict(sorted(x.items())).values() for x in d)))` could do here?

Answer (score 2):

Given that all dictionaries in your list will have the same keys, you can use a dictionary and list comprehension:

```
>>> {k: [d.get(k) for d in my_list_of_dicts] for k in my_list_of_dicts[0]}
{50: [2, 5, 8], 75: [3, 6, 9], 99: [4, 7, 10]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is 3 individual *lists* you could create each *list* with *list comprehension*

```
l = [{50: 2, 75: 3, 99: 4}, {50: 5, 75: 6, 99: 7}, {50: 8, 75: 9, 99:10}]

l_50 = [v for i in l for k, v in i.items() if k == 50] # => [2, 5, 8]
l_75 = [v for i in l for k, v in i.items() if k == 75] # => [3, 6, 9]
l_99 = [v for i in l for k, v in i.items() if k == 99] # => [4, 7, 10]
```

Or you can construct a *dictionary* and look up each *list* by `key`

```
d = {k: [j[x] for j in l for x in j if x == k] for i in l for k in i}
```

> ```
> {50: [2, 5, 8], 75: [3, 6, 9], 99: [4, 7, 10]}
> ```